# I am not allowed to change the declaration of my variable, what other ways can I edit my code?

Tags: c++, microcontroller

I know this warning have been asked many times. But I can't think of how to edit my code.

*I only include the code on the error/warning part.*

```
const unsigned char *ad[100];
unsigned long long ad[100];

int main
{
    adlen = CDC_Device_BytesReceived(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);  
    if(adlen > 0)
    {
        ad[i] = CDC_Device_ReceiveByte(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
        i++;
        adlen--;
    }
}
```

After compiling, I will get a warning.

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ad[i] = CDC_Device_ReceiveByte(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
      ^
```

I also tried searching online for another way to declare.

```
const unsigned char *ad; //or const unsigned char *ad = malloc(100);
unsigned long long ad[100];

int main
{
    adlen = CDC_Device_BytesReceived(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);  
    if(adlen > 0)
    {
        ad[i] = CDC_Device_ReceiveByte(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
        i++;
        adlen--;
    }
}
```

But I will end up getting an error

```
error: assignment of read-only location '(ad + (sizetype)((unsigned int)i * 1u))'
ad[i] = CDC_Device_ReceiveByte(&VirtualSerial_CDC_Interface);
      ^
```

I cannot change and have to declare `const unsigned char *ad` as a pointer so I have to probably add/change something to my code in int main but I cannot think of how/what to do.

I will be glad if anyone can help/guide me on what to do with this warning and error. Thank you!

Comment: Does `CDC_Device_ReceiveByte` return a pointer or an integer? If it's an integer, what is your intent with that line? `ad` is an array of pointers. Did you intend for it to be just an array of chars?

Comment: @AKL It looks like the error is with the assignment of the result of `CDC_Device_ReceiveByte` and `ad[i]`, not inside `CDC_Device_ReceiveByte`.

Comment: Please use a proper C++ container, not an array with a "magic" size of `100` which you hope will always be big enough.

Comment: `CDC_Device_BytesReceived` returns an unsigned integer. Are you calling the correct function there? You're calling it there, and right above that line as well, and `adlen` suggests your intent in calling that function is to get a length. I think you meant to call something else there. `CDC_Device_ReceiveByte` maybe? (although that doesn't return a char pointer either)

Comment: @aschepler This is microcontroller programming. There I would avoid dynamic memory allocation like it is used in STL containers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate adlen is declared as unsigned long long. I was trying to do a loop, so as long as there are bytesreceived, ad will receive a byte from the host until adlen > 0 becomes false.

Answer (score 2):

The function `CDC_Device_ReceiveByte` returns a value of type `int16_t` so you need

```
int16_t ad[100];
```

Comment: I am not allowed to change the declaration of variable. Are there any other ways I can edit my code?

Comment: @jan nothing that doesn't delve into questionable behaviour.  You can silence the error with a cast, but that error's there for a reason.

Comment: @jan If you are not allowed to change the declaration of this variable, you should ask, why you have to use a wrong type to store the returned value. Maybe you are using the wrong function. But this question can't be answered by us.